# Preguntas pidiendo recomendaciones... ¿están dentro de la temática de esSO?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

En el sitio original, una de las razones para cerrar preguntas fuera de temática (*off-topic*) es:

> *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

(Traducción aproximada)

> Preguntas que piden **recomendaciones de libros, herramientas, bibliotecas de software, tutoriales u otro recurso externo** están fuera de la temática de StackOverflow pues tienen a a traer respuestas basadas en opiniones o spam. En lugar de ello, describe el problema y lo que se ha hecho hasta ahora para resolverlo.

Me topé con [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/871/alternativas-a-eclipse-para-desarrollar-en-j2ee), y yo estaría de acuerdo con votar para que se cierre. Pero antes de lanzar votos de cierre, quisiera saber si hay una posicion al respecto. Así que, en concreto:

- Las preguntas que piden recomendaciones de software, libros, tutoriales... ¿deben cerrarse?

Comment: según [comentarios](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26194963#26194963) de @JuanM en el chat, vamos a aceptar este tipo de preguntas. al menos por ahora.

Comment: @rnrneverdies ¡Muchas gracias! Si puedes, publica tu comentario como respuesta (para que sea visible en caso de que otros tengan la misma inquietud que yo)

Comment: @rnrneverdies pensaba que esto entraba dentro de "basado en opiniones" y no muy productivo.